# How to show sub menu in Ext Js?

Tags: extjs

I have a scenario where i have splitbutton which i am able to expand using showMenu function.

var comp = Ext.getCmp('Submenu1');
comp.showMenu();

The menu thus opened has another submenu. I tried using the same showMenu function to expand it, but it didn't work. Do we have some function like showMenu for menuitems in extjs?

[image]

***Properties of MenuItem***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used following snippet to expand the sub menu item.Just before doExpandMenu i had to activate the element.

```
window.c = Ext.getCmp('TabBar:AdminTab');
c.showMenu();
c = Ext.getCmp('TabBar:AdminTab:Admin_UsersAndSecurity');
c.activate()
c.doExpandMenu();
c.deactivate();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course, otherwise ExtJS couldn't open the menu as well... 
they didn't make the function part of their public API, but this doesn't mean you can't use it. (they may change the behaviour without notice in updates - but if you don't read every line of their release notes carefully, you won't feel the difference...)

In ExtJS, menu items are of xtype `menuitem`, which has a `doExpandMenu` function.

I made [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1c9k) for you.

Comment: Hi Alexander, Sorry for responding back to late. i made one small tweek and it worked for me.

Comment: Hi Alexander, with the update to EXTJS 5.1 activate function is deprecated and now i am unable to expand menus

Comment: @DevX I have switched my fiddle to 5.1.4 and it works. If you have a problem, try to reproduce in a fiddle and then ask a new question, with a link to the fiddle that shows the problem.

Comment: Sadly i don't have access to code. I am Automating an ExtJS Application using javascript. I have attached few of the screenshot that might help

Comment: Hi Alexander...I did try few things and found out that sub menu items are not being rendered that is why doExpandMenu is not working. Sub menu items are rendered on Mouse over. Is there a way by which i can render submenu items and then use doExpandMenu.